# Nonlinear parabolic PDEs existence with Galerkin method?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Can someone give me some references to read where existence/uniqueness of nonlinear parabolic PDE are treated via the Galerkin method or fixed point methods or something like that (anything but semigroups, which I am not faimilar with)?

I always come across H. Amann's work when I search on this topic but his work appears a bit complicated to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is difficult to have something without semigroups, since [Lunardi](http://books.google.de/books/about/Analytic_Semigroups_and_Optimal_Regulari.html?id=mWojiHzg9bEC&redir_esc=y) is still one of the most comprehensive references.

Try [Krylov](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-96) then, it is an excellent read.

If you are fixed on Galerkin, then [Zeidler:](http://books.google.de/books/about/Nonlinear_Functional_Analysis_and_Its_Ap.html?id=MFi9SkoK750C&redir_esc=y) *Nonlinear Functional Analysis and Its Applications: Part 2 B: Nonlinear Monotone Operators* is a good start.

Comment: @user35613: I will update it when I get to some resourses, it is not easy during summertime.